# The identity of "imap.gmail.com" cannot be verified

Tags: macbook-pro, imap

Has anyone come across this issue?

[image]

What is going on and how do you solve it? Is pressing confirm okay?

This occurred when I went into MacBooks Notes app where I keep my notes.

Here is some of the **Details** when expanded:

[image]

Comment: Is your computer date/time set correctly?

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes that is correct.

Comment: What does it show for the "Google Internet Authority G3" certificate (note that it also has a red X on its icon)? Expanding the "Details" section for both "X" certificates might also give useful information.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, I have provided some of the details of **Details**. Perhaps it can help you help me? Seeing the SHA fingerprints, Certificate Policies, CRL Distribution Points and so on do not help me figure out what to do here. Never had this problem before in just opening Notes.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Date & Time settings in preferences. Make sure that the date is correct.

Comment: date and time are correct. No issue there.